# Youtube Data API List Channels by guideCategoryId

Tags: youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&categoryId=GCVGVjaA&key={apikey}

This request works in the API Explorer with results, but returns zero results when accessed with HTTP. Do I need permissions to find a list of channels?

On ChannelCrawler, you can search by category
http://www.channelcrawler.com/results/20266

This is the response I'm trying to get with my key, which I am able to get from the API Explorer.

```
{ 
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/8d1Un14y7eaF8GbkAIoZTSq3PVs\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 30,
 "resultsPerPage": 5
},
"items": [
 {


  "kind": "youtube#channel",
  "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/vGcWdxlMxYNl0RvCvjrlY5S6jtg\"",
  "id": "UCDlQwv99CovKafGvxyaiNDA",
  "snippet": {
  "title": "Jonathan Morrison",
  "description": "High quality videos blending tech + aesthetic, showcasing 
the latest products & gadgets.",
  "customUrl": "TLD",
  "publishedAt": "2010-03-24T22:28:10.000Z",
  "thumbnails": {
   "default": {
   "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-0DW8rFVe_fY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/kEQu5GMM8g4/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-0DW8rFVe_fY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/kEQu5GMM8g4/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-0DW8rFVe_fY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/kEQu5GMM8g4/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
 }
},
"localized": {
 "title": "Jonathan Morrison",
 "description": "High quality videos blending tech + aesthetic, showcasing the latest products & gadgets."
},
"country": "US"
  }
},
{ ...
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score -2):

I'm the creator of the Channel Crawler, and yes, getting the category of a channel was a bit of a challenge. It's not part of the channel data itself, so you have to use a workaround.

The trick that I used is to load the 10 newest video on a channel (which you can find by accessing a channel's Upload Playlist ID) into an array. Then I can just iterate over them and check every video's category. The category that's used the most is selected as the channel category.

If you have more questions about this, my contact details are on the website that you linked above.

Comment: I appreciate it.